# JSTL Library Tags Error, NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, foreach, nullpointerexception

I am using spring 5.3.7, and in my JSP  I added the line below

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

When I start my application, Its responde the error below

> [10/29/21 10:23:38:455 CDT] 000000c8 ServletWrappe E
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An
> exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet
> [/WEB-INF/jsp/private/inicio.jsp] in application [MyApplication].
> Exception created : [java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
> at com.ibm._jsp._main._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(_main.java:1225)   at
> com.ibm._jsp._main._jspService(_main.java:358).

The object response has data, I validated it, but for testing I add the line below, but the error continues.

```
<c:forEach var = "i" items="1,4,5,6,7,8,9"> 

  Item <c:out value = "No. ${i}"/><p> 

</c:forEach>
```

Also, I have below dependency in my pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note. This issue is only with JSTL Tags, if I remove the code of JSTL, my application start without problems.

I hope someone can help me, thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no reason this piece of Expression language would throw a NullPointerException. Are you sure there isn't another EL statement that could throw it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I did debug and test, I dont´n know why, but any jstl tag don´t work.